# How to maintain URL in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am new in CakePHP. I have one query about the URL in CakePHP.

I have one project in CakePHP. when i am accessing the project using localhost like below example.

http://example.com/

then it will be convert in to these URL

http://example.com/vadodara/users/login

I want to know how to above URL convert when I access project using localhost.

please give me guideline how to find it in my project

Thanks in advance
Ramesh Prajapati

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

It should be routing

Go to www/project/app/config/routes.php

You should see something like this

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'main'));

change it to the path or url you prefer